# Am I stuck in an endless battle?

Tags: ftl-faster-than-light

[image]

As you can see, I cannot escape because my fuel is empty.
The enemy can't penetrate my shield but I can't damage him either.
What could I do other than killing my crew by opening my airlocks?

Comment: Well, you could also turn your shields off and let them shoot you. ;)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

**Nothing, you are doomed.**

Sorry to say it, but sometimes that's just the way it is.

[image: Game Over]

Comment: Well I had seen this coming.

Comment: @Sevensideddie what does putting text in those brackets do?

Comment: @Ender it's the alt text

Comment: whats alt text?

Comment: It's what shows up to people with images turned off (or before they load on slow connections), what's heard in screen readers, and in textual renderings of the page in general (such as text previews and search engine indices). That's why the default tells you to "enter description here". :)

Comment: @Ender It's also used by Google to populate image search results.